# Add validation to salesforce.com forms

Tags: php, forms, validation, salesforce

I've been tasked with adding validation to stop spam on a simple contact form. The only problem here is that all the form processing happens on salesforce.com's side. I don't have the file that processes the form so I can't just add simple form validation.

The form's action goes to salesforce as so:

```
<form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
```

I tried doing some javascript validation, but the form still submits no matter what. I have a feeling I need to change the form's action to a new php page I create. I can do the validation there, then if it passes I need to tell it to somehow go to this form action and finish the form processing?

I tried doing the hidden form field idea with jQuery, where you put in a hidden form field that only a bot would somehow fill out. So if that field has a value, then do an alert that it is spam, but this wouldn't work! The form just kept submitting.

Ugh, not sure, please help thanks!

=====EDIT====

What is wrong here?

my button

```
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">
```

my jquery

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

```
jQuery('#submit').click(function() {

    var human = $("#human").val();

    if(human == 4 ){
        $('#form_submit').submit();
    }

    else {
        alert('Please answer the validation question correctly.');
    }
});
```

});

my form action:

```
<form id="form_submit" action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
```

and my "human" field:

```
<input  id="human" maxlength="20" name="human" size="30" type="text" />
```

Comment: You could use AJAX for that,

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work:

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/r84LW/1/)

you want to prevent the default event that happens on form submission.

SO when they click enter, or submit, you want to **`preventDefault()`**, then you are free to do what you want. I did ajax as example, because ajax is awesome.

```
<form id="form_submit" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="for humans" id="email">
<input type="text" name="robots" value="" placeholder="for robots" id="human">
<input type="submit" value="GO!">
```

```
<script>
$("#form_submit").submit(function(e){
  // when the form is submitted:
  // if the value of #human isn't empty, its a robot
  if ($("#human").val() !== "") {
    alert('robot!');
    return false;
  }

  // other form validation you may want:
  if ($("#email").val() == ""){
    alert('missing email');
    return false;
  }

  // STOP THE FORM FROM SUBMITTING ON ITS OWN
  e.preventDefault();

  // do whatever else you have to do.
  $.ajax({
     url:"https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8",
     data:"field1=value1&field2=value2", // this depends on what your server-side wants
     type:"POST",
     beforeSend:function(){console.log('sending..');},
     error:function(response){console.log('error: ' + response);},
     success:function(response){console.log('success!');},
     complete:function(){console.log('finished.');}
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like salesforce isn't liking this, I get the error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8. Origin http://hidden.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: did you update the code for your own inputs? and are you running it in jsfiddle? jsfiddle can't connect to your salesforce...

Answer (score -1):

Change your submit button to a normal button. In jQuery add a `click` method to perform your spam logic. When you really want to submit you can submit the page through jQuery.

Example:

```
<form id="form_submit" action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method=" POST">

$("#submit").click(function() {
  if(!spam){
    $('#form_submit').submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey, I can handle the form validation part, but how can i do the second part? "When you really want to submit you can re-add the action to the form to the salesforce link and then submit the page through jQuery"...Any link to a tutorial or something? Thanks

Comment: changed my answer to have that

Comment: I editted my question with my new attempt but no luck, any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Have you checked for Javascript errors in the console or firebug?